# PHP, syslog don't write error message to the error file

Tags: php, debugging, logging, syslog

I try logging php errors. My code is here:

```
<?php
  echo ini_get('error_log');          //output D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
  echo ini_get('log_errors');         //output 1
  echo ini_get('error_reporting');    //output 32767= E_ALL

  openlog('myapplication', LOG_PERROR, 0);
  syslog(LOG_ERR, "Something bad has happened");
  closelog();
?>
```

But, no errors message is put in php_error_log file. Where is the problem?
I have MS Windows 7 Professional and PHP Version 5.4.19.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked every other log file in your log folder/locations? From reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php it seems that it might not go into `php_error_log`.

Another point gathered in the documentation is:

> On Windows NT, the syslog service is emulated using the Event Log.

I know it says `NT` but it might have remained the same all this time. You might want to check the event viewer. I am on linux currently but I imagine its something like this:

```
Control Panel -> Administration -> Event Viewer
```

Edit: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/open-event-viewer

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found my php logs in "Event Viewer".
Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Event Viewer.‌ Thank's for advice. I found my php logs in "Event Viewer".